# Will Allah forgive me

Tags: allah, sin, islamic-basis, forgiveness, masturbation

Aoa, I am a 16 year old boy and for the past 2 years I had been addicted to masturbation and pornography but at first I didn't know it was haram, when I got to know I tried to reduce it and repent but everytime I would fail,last year I reduced it that I used to masturbate once a week, Then this year I made a promise to myself and Allah that I will try to not do it again and repented truly, Alhamdullilah I was able to quit it and didn't masturbate for 5 months but yesterday I accidentally opened adult content and semen came out( I didn't use my hand), I am so ashamed cuz I was able to control for such a long time and ik Allah doesn't forgive if u keep on doing it but this happened after many months and I had no intention to sin and feel very bad and I'm trying to repent will Allah forgive me?

Answer (score 0):

"ik Allah doesn’t forgive if u keep on doing it". This is utterly false. Allah is the most forgiving, he forgives ALL SINS before the Sun rises from the west.

**ALLAH WILL FORGIVE YOU.**, even if you sin 1 million times, as long as you repent sincerely.

To help with your case, fast (because fasting reduces sexual desires) or marry to a woman (to fulfill your sexual desires in a halal way).